# Is it allowed to incentivize people to subscribe to my channel using YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have some content on my website. I want people to be able to unlock this content by subscribing to my youtube channel using the YouTube API. Is this allowed?

I read it's against the terms for the embedded Javascript 'Subscribe Button' to give users incentives to subscribe: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button ("You may not offer or promote prizes or rewards of any kind in exchange for clicking on a YouTube Subscribe Button.")
**However**, when the subscription is created programmatically using the Google Apps/YouTube API, I'm not using the YouTube Subscribe button.

On the Google Apps/YouTube API terms (https://developers.google.com/terms/ & https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) there's no statement about rewarding users for subscribing when the subscription is made using the YouTube API.
Does this mean it's permitted?
Can I reward users for subscribing to my channel if the subscriptions are made/checked programmatically using the Google Apps/YouTube API?

Comment: There's a specific list of 'Prohibitions' in the YouTube API Terms, and rewarding subscriptions isn't in that list.: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms
Is it safe to assume it's permitted then?

Answer (score 1):

The API docs also forbid the use of rewards/incentives etc...

API Clients must not offer or provide incentives, rewards, or other compensation to users for engaging with YouTube Applications (directly or indirectly) by performing actions like viewing content, liking content, sharing content, subscribing to channels, adding comments. For example, API Clients must not offer features or services that trade video views for a fee or that trade video views in return for other YouTube-related or non-YouTube-related actions.

developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies